# Sparql Delete statement Jena OWL

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I'm trying to delete all triples, I have these functions,

class variables

```
public static String defaultNameSpace = "http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2016/3/Inventory#";
public Model Inventario = null;
public Model schema = null;
public String DatabaseFile = "PR2INVENTARIORDFXML.owl";
public OutputStream output;

public ResultSet runQuery(String queryRequest, Model model)
{
    StringBuffer queryStr = new StringBuffer();
    ResultSet response = null;
    // Establish Prefixes
    //Set default Name space first
    queryStr.append("PREFIX base: <" + defaultNameSpace + "> ");
    queryStr.append("PREFIX rdfs: <" + "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" + "> ");
    queryStr.append("PREFIX rdf: <" + "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" + "> ");
    queryStr.append("PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>");

    //Now add query
    queryStr.append(queryRequest);
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr.toString());
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    try
    {
        response = qexec.execSelect();
    }
    finally { }

    return response;
}
```

I have functions for each query, here is an example

```
public ResultSet AllRecords(Model model)
{
    return runQuery("select ?s ?p ?o where{?s ?p ?o."
                    + "} " , model); 
}
```

When I try to run these queries

```
public ResultSet BorrarPC(Model model)
{
    return runQuery("DELETE {base:PC1 ?p ?o} " +
                    "WHERE {base:PC1 ?p ?o}" +
                     "" , model); 
}

public ResultSet eraseAllTriples(Model model)
{
    return runQuery("DELETE {?s ?p ?o} " +
                    "WHERE {?s ?p ?o}" +
                     "" , model); 
}
```

It gives me these error

```
run:
```

Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 1, column 233.
Was expecting one of:
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "describe" ...
    "construct" ...
    "ask" ...

```
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:87)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse(ParserSPARQL11.java:40)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:132)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:69)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:28)
at explorerowlexample.FinalProject.runQuery(FinalProject.java:146)
at explorerowlexample.FinalProject.BorrarPC(FinalProject.java:90)
at explorerowlexample.FinalProject.main(FinalProject.java:56)
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

How to create a delete statement?

Comment: `com.hp.hpl.jena` shows you are using an old version. Nowadays, Jena3, all packages are `org.apache.jena`.

Answer (score 3):

A SPARQL Update request is not a query.

You need to use the update API: See `UpdateExecutionFactory`.